# How to dynamically render a color for a specific metric in AWS using a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a code like this:

```
import boto3
import random
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    response = cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
        MetricData = [
            {
                'MetricName': 'KPIs',
                'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'PURCHASES_SERVICE',
                        'Value': 'CoolService'
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'APP_VERSION',
                        'Value': '1.0'
                    },
                ],
                'Unit': 'Percent',
                'Value': random.randint(1, 100),
                'color': 'red'
            },
        ],
        Namespace = 'CoolApp'
    )
    print(response)
```

My goal is to set a custom color for this metric.
Like, when its 0 %, the metric color should be red etc.

Does anybody know a way, how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this is not possible. The [MetricDatum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_MetricDatum.html) that you send to the [PutMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html) API does not include any color options.

Comment: maybe, there is another approach, like different API, how to do it. My goal is to dynamically change the color of the metric depending on a value

Comment: As far as I know, you can't assign colors to the data at source. The color choices are made by the software that visualizes the data, and I presume you are looking at the AWS CloudWatch console so you're limited by whatever options it provides.